# PDO fetch causes 500 internal error

Tags: php, sql, pdo, odbc

I'm getting an error when I try to fetch the result of a PDO query. I've narrowed it down to the content of the column, but I'm not sure why it's causing this, or how to fix this. This is not a typical PHP error as there's nothing in the error log. In fact, I think it's crashing PHP altogether. Any ideas on what the issue is?

Note: the DB variable is a PDO connection to ODBC. (going to MSSQL)

```
$query = $Z->DB->query("SELECT TOP 1 id, ticket, typeid, issued, comment, privatecomment FROM Handheld_IncomingTickets WHERE processed is null ORDER BY issued asc");
// No error.
if (!$query->execute()) {
    $moreData = false;
    echo dump($query->errorInfo()) ." ".__FILE__." at Line: ".__LINE__;
    break;
}
// No error.
$record = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// ERROR!
```

This is the content of the comment column of one of the records that cause the 500 error. This is just test data, the comment column wouldn't have a dump of the $_POST variable in production, but i'm confused as to why it matters. I could clear out all the values that look like this, but if I don't find out what's causing the issue, I can't be certain that this won't happen again with valid data.

```
array (   'act' => 'push',   'ticket' => '35-0191',   'ticket_int' => '191',   'vehicleid' => 'null',   'plate' => '028RLS',   'platetypeid' => 'null',   'provid' => '9',   'makeid' => '1',   'typeid' => '1',   'colourid' => '1',   'year' => 'null',   'locationid' => 'null',   'permitno' => 'null',   'sempermitid' => 'null',   'tickettype' => 'null',   'issued' => '2012-10-02%2013%3A22%3A31',   'violationtypeid' => 'null',   'writer' => '17',   'fine' => 'null',   'towing' => '',   'comment' => '',   'privatecomment' => '',   'synced' => 'null', )
```

This is the error that I see in the event logs on the server.

```
Faulting application name: php-cgi.exe, version: 5.3.12.0, time stamp: 0x4fa94d46
Faulting module name: php5.dll, version: 5.3.12.0, time stamp: 0x4fa94db5
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000c3b6
Faulting process id: 0x2a0
Faulting application start time: 0x01cdaadbbdc7fb98
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php5.dll
Report Id: fbc37d92-16ce-11e2-9dcf-ca21ba90502f
```

Comment: I can use another scripting language to retrieve the data fine. I can also query directly on the sql server and the results pull up fine.

Comment: Is this reproducible on other machines, or only on one particular server? Maybe a bad library in that installation?

Comment: PHP 5.3.12 is known to have errors. The current bugfix release of it is PHP 5.3.17. I would at least test against that newer version as well.

Comment: I'll try putting .17 on first.

Comment: .17 did the trick. The version that's available through Microsoft's Web Installer is behind and I didn't think to install the latest from php.net. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.17 did the trick. The version that's available through Microsoft's Web Installer is behind and I didn't think to install the latest from php.net. Thanks.

+1 to hakre